# Randomly dropping rows with a condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that is unbalanced such as:

```
tag    #elements    
a      1500
b      3250
c      320   
d      260
```

It causes overfitting. I want to eleminate some of the rows that have certain name randomly so my dataset will be more balanced. For example after elemination I want something like this;

```
tag    #elements    
a      300
b      300
c      300
d      260
```

But, I appriciate it, if possible to eleminate them randomly between some range such as lowest number of elements (260 in our case), plus 50 or so (I don't know the right way to perform it.). So, after elemination number of elements will be something like this:

```
tag    #elements    
a      307
b      286
c      275
d      260
```

Please note that, these numbers corresponds to the number of tags. Length of dataset is 5330 in total. I want to reduce it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use upsampling for this? simply duplicate the data to balance it.

Comment: that might work but i thought doing that may cause overfitting too. using same data for 12-15 times may cause tag d to overfit somehow and things that needs to be on d class may go to other. am i wrong ?

Comment: you are right at some extent. That's why people generally combine upsampling and downsampling. You can find sweet spot (between 1000-2000 in your case) and upsample the labels which have less value and downsample the ones which have more values.

Comment: actually my problem starts at there to downsample these to reasonable place by selecting randomly

Comment: You can subset your data and use `random` module to generate random number to select data points with these index.

Comment: whats your actual wanted output, is it second or third ? if it is third, then what is the condition for that value

Comment: maybe have a look at [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), it could help you about the random idea

Answer (score 0):

using [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), you can do it this way:

```
#create a dataframe like yours
df = pd.DataFrame({'tag':['a']*1500 + ['b']*3250 + ['c']*320 + ['d']*260,'col1':range(5330)})
min_size = df.groupby('tag').count().min()[0] #here it's 260
max_plus = 50
df_sample = (df.groupby('tag',as_index=False)
               .apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(len(x), min_size + np.random.randint(max_plus,size=1))))
               .reset_index(drop=True)) # this is not mandatory, it depends of your needs
```

and then for example with my try:

```
print (df_sample.groupby('tag').count())
Out[292]: 
     col1
tag      
a     270
b     299
c     287
d     260
```